# Accessing information nested second level deep in an array using React Native ‘fetch’ method

Tags: arrays, database, react-native, object, fetch

I can access information on the top level of array. But I can’t access things on the second level down in the database.

I’m using the basic ‘Fetch’ method from here:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network

And this is the database I’m trying to access. 
(I stripped off my API key from the URL but it looks like it still works. In case it doesn't work anymore for you, I've copy & pasted the content down below in the code section.) 
https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Line/london-overground/Status

I want to access the short description text of the current line status (such as “minor delay”, “reduced service” and so on). 
The information in question is stored under “lineStatuses”/ “statusSeverityDescription” in the database.

See below what I've tried so far with Expo Snack samples.

**Option 1)**

https://snack.expo.io/@leourushi/api-call-01

If I use

```
{item.name}
```

It correctly returns the name of the line.

However, if I try this,

```
{item.lineStatuses.statusSeverityDescription}
```

The screen will return nothing.

**Option 2)**

https://snack.expo.io/@leourushi/api-call-02

I modified the initial instance of dataSource like this:

```
dataSource: responseJson[0].lineStatuses
```

And then, I tried to return this:

```
{item.statusSeverityDescription}
```

This time, it correctly returns the line status description text. But the Android emulator returns this error message:

“Failed child context type: Invalid child context `virtualizedCell.cellKey` of type `number` supplied to `CellRenderer`, expected `string`...

Below is the content of the database when I checked earlier. (You will also see the same database in the Expo links above)

```
[
  {
    "$type": "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Line, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
    "id": "london-overground",
    "name": "London Overground",
    "modeName": "overground",
    "disruptions": [],
    "created": "2019-06-03T16:21:44.04Z",
    "modified": "2019-06-03T16:21:44.04Z",
    "lineStatuses": [
      {
        "$type": "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.LineStatus, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
        "id": 0,
        "lineId": "london-overground",
        "statusSeverity": 7,
        "statusSeverityDescription": "Reduced Service",
        "reason": "LONDON OVERGROUND: Until further notice, reduced service between Gospel Oak and Barking. A temporary timetable is in place, with four car trains running every 30 minutes. New trains may provide additional services, resulting in an increased frequency. Tuesday 28, Wednesday 29, Thursday 30 and Friday 31 May, the 2313 Barking to Gospel Oak service will terminate at Upper Holloway at 23:40 and the 23:25 train from Gospel Oak to Barking will not run and the last departure will be at 22:48",
        "created": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "validityPeriods": [
          {
            "$type": "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.ValidityPeriod, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
            "fromDate": "2019-05-20T03:30:00Z",
            "toDate": "2019-08-25T01:29:00Z",
            "isNow": false
          }
        ],
        "disruption": {
          "$type": "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Disruption, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
          "category": "Information",
          "categoryDescription": "Information",
          "description": "LONDON OVERGROUND: Until further notice, reduced service between Gospel Oak and Barking. A temporary timetable is in place, with four car trains running every 30 minutes. New trains may provide additional services, resulting in an increased frequency. Tuesday 28, Wednesday 29, Thursday 30 and Friday 31 May, the 2313 Barking to Gospel Oak service will terminate at Upper Holloway at 23:40 and the 23:25 train from Gospel Oak to Barking will not run and the last departure will be at 22:48",
          "additionalInfo": "For train times see the <a href=\"http://content.tfl.gov.uk/gospel-oak-to-barking-temporary-timetable-march-2019.pdf?5\">temporary timetable</a>. For more information and travel options, visit <a href=\"https://tfl.gov.uk/modes/london-overground/gospel-oak-to-barking-improvements?cid=gospel-oak-barking-trains\">tfl.gov.uk/gospel-oak-barking-trains</a>",
          "created": "2019-05-14T14:07:00Z",
          "affectedRoutes": [],
          "affectedStops": [],
          "closureText": "reducedService"
        }
      }
    ],
    "routeSections": [],
    "serviceTypes": [
      {
        "$type": "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.LineServiceTypeInfo, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
        "name": "Regular",
        "uri": "/Line/Route?ids=London Overground&serviceTypes=Regular"
      },
      {
        "$type": "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.LineServiceTypeInfo, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
        "name": "Night",
        "uri": "/Line/Route?ids=London Overground&serviceTypes=Night"
      }
    ],
    "crowding": {
      "$type": "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Crowding, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities"
    }
  }
]
```

I’d like a pointer on how to extract information from things buried in the second level down in an array using React Native. 
I don’t need to loop through the database. I only need to extract one thing from there.

Comment: Seems to be a problem with your key format being a number. Use option 2 (this is the correct way to populate your dataSource), and add ```.toString()``` to your key extractor, like this - ```keyExtractor={({id}, index) => id.toString()}```

Comment: @Jono Perfect! That did it. Now I can extract a single item nested within the array. Thank you! Do you mind posting that as an answer so I can upvote/ accept as official answer?

Comment: Sure! Glad to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a problem with your key format being a number.

Use option 2 (this is the correct way to populate your dataSource), and add `.toString()` to your key extractor, like this - `keyExtractor={({id}, index) => id.toString()}`

Comment: This fixed my problem. Thank you.